# Parsing JsonArray in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have this kind of json but retrofit can't parse it.

```
[
 {
   "title": "Questions1"
 },
 {
   "title": "Questions2"
 }
]
```

I went to this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create an object, then calling the api it went to the onFailure and says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`.

This is my APiInterface:

```
Call<MyObject> asdf(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

Comment: it is an Array. Your interface method, should return`Call<List<PoJo>>`

Answer (score 0):

Your json is an jsonArray,so you can't get the value like get jsonobject,it should return `Call<List<PoJo>>`,not `Call<PoJo>`,like this:

```
Call<List<MyObject>> asdf(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

Comment: Thank you !! but I can't upvote, not enough reputation

Comment: @user3777553  it's no matter,hope you can gain more reputation by your effort.If this answer can help you can accept it ,then others can know this answer is useful to solve their similar problem.